# String inside a quote

Tags: c++, prepared-statement, mysql-connector

So the documentation for the *C++ connector mysql* says:

```
sql::Connection *con;
sql::PreparedStatement  *prep_stmt
// ...

prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test(id, label) VALUES (?, ?)");

prep_stmt->setString(2, "a");
prep_stmt->execute();
```

But when I type in my code

```
  pstmt = con->prepareStatement("UPDATE master SET movie='?' WHERE choice='Y'");
  pstmt->setString(1, str);
  pstmt->execute();
```

It tells me I'm not allowed to do that after I run the program.

> Unhandled exception at 0x75c24b32 in Camera Command Line.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: sql::InvalidArgumentException at memory
>   location 0x00dbe59c..

I understand that it's telling me I can't do this, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Do you need the quotes around the '?' in the update call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a prepared statment so you do not need to quote the `bound` variables in the SQL, you should do this:

```
pstmt = con->prepareStatement("UPDATE master SET movie=? WHERE choice='Y'");
                                                      ^^^
```